# slideshow inside fancybox

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a#logo").fancybox({
                'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
            }).trigger('click');
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <a id="logo" href="../../images/mav/mission.png"><img id="imageSlide" alt="imageSlide" src="images/banners2/banner1.png" style="height:255px; border:none; margin-top:0px; margin-left:0px;"  align="middle"/></a>
</center>
</body>
```

.hi guys based on the code above i currently have a fancybox that pops up On-page-load. right now it is currently displaying the image inside the href="" attribute. What can i do to have the image switch into another image with an interval of 8seconds for example. I only have two images actually and i want them to automatically switch every 8seconds.

Comment: This could help you I think

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019533/slideshow-in-fancybox-image-gallery

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery Cycle then http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
            timeout: 8000
    });
});

<div class="slideshow"> 
        <a href="linkHere"><img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" /></a> 
        <a href="linkHere"><img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" /></a> 
    </div>
```

Comment: .I think that would be useless because i haven't declared any pictures to switch to.

Comment: Maybe fancybox is not a solution then for that kind of thing. This could be more appropriate I think: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Answer (score 0):

Just curios - doesn't fancybox load up a div?

Could you place a slider within that `div`?

[jQuery slider](http://slidesjs.com/)

So you would setup a `div` within your fancbox div and do this:

```
$(function(){
  $("#slides").slides({
       play: 5000,
       effect: 'fade',
       slideSpeed: 8000,
       crossfade: true,
       fadeEasing: "easeOutQuad",
       hoverPause: false
  });
});
```

Sorry if I'm misunderstanding how fancybox works.