# Cycle Plugin only works if there is <img> predefined?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I have following to do the photo slideshow:

```
$('#Yeah').click(function() {
    {% for photo in photos %}
    $('#slideShow').append('<img src="/image?blob_key={{ photo }}" />');
    % endfor %}

    $('#slideShow').cycle({ 
      fx:     'fade',
      speed:  300, 
      next:   '#slideShow', 
      timeout: 0 
    });
});
```

When I have empty img tag under the div tag, the slideshow won't work at all.

```
<div id="slideShow">

</div>
```

However, if I at least add one img tag under the div tag, it works with the same codes.

```
<div id="slideShow">
    <img class="pics" width="200" height="200"> 
</div>
```

Does anyone have any clue what's the problem ? Any helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that the images are not fully loaded before the Cycle plugin is initialized.

Looking through [the source of the "lite" version](https://raw.github.com/malsup/cycle/master/jquery.cycle.lite.js), I see:

```
    $slides.each(function() {
        var $el = $(this);
        this.cycleH = (opts.fit && opts.height) ? opts.height : $el.height();
        this.cycleW = (opts.fit && opts.width) ? opts.width : $el.width();
    });
```

Because you do not specify the `width` and `height` options, it defaults to the width and height of the `<img>` element, which are both 0 when the image is not fully loaded.

**EDIT:** Try:

```
    var imgEls = $([]);

    {% for photo in photos %}
    imgEls = imgEls.add($('<img src="/image?blob_key={{ photo|urlencode }}" />'));
    {% endfor %}

    var numLoaded = 0;
    imgEls.load(function () {
        ++numLoaded;

        if (numLoaded == imgEls.length) {
            $('#slideShow').cycle({ 
                fx:     'fade',
                speed:   300
            });
        }
    });

    imgEls.appendTo($('#slideShow'));
```

**EDIT2:** There is a syntax error:

```
$(this\).ajaxSubmit(options);
```

needs to be:

```
$(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
//    ^ No backslash character '\'
```

Comment: Do you know why I have to press the button (id="Yeah") twice only it will refresh accordingly? Actually, the button is for me to test it. My intention is to let it load under $(document).ready(function() 

Any idea how to put workaround on this?

Comment: It's actually working by placing the code imgEls.appendTo($('#slideShow')); before executing the slideShow function....

However, when I put it under $(document).ready(function() without being in the button function, it's no longer working. Any idea?

Comment: @MrCooL: Do you mean that you build up `imgEls`, append them to `$('#slideShow')`, and then immediately call the Cycle plugin? As I said in my answer, I don't think that that will work because the images have not been fully loaded. I edited my answer slightly. Please try that code and let me know if it works.

Comment: Still not working. BTW, I actually need to set the fixed width and height for each of this image, will that affect the codes you posted here?

Comment: @MrCooL: No, setting widths and heights explicitly should be fine. Do you have the web page on a web server so that I can see the issue(s) for myself?

Comment: http://foodsuggest.appspot.com/restaurant_profile?restaurant_key=ag1zfmZvb2RzdWdnZXN0chELEgpSZXN0YXVyYW50IgEyDA

You should be able to access this. You have to click on the photo link.

Comment: @MrCooL: Looking through the generated code, you don't need `$(function () {` and the matching `});` because it's already within a DOM ready handler (`$(document).ready(function() { ... });`). What is not working? It seems to work in Firefox. Do I need to try a different browser?

Comment: @MrCooL: Note that the way you have the Cycle plugin configured, the user has to click on the image to see the next one. If you want it to flip through the images automatically, then remove the `next` and `timeout` options. (I updated my answer.)

Comment: @MrCooL: I see that you are making some changes already. Note that there is a syntax error in the current JavaScript code. See **EDIT2** of my answer.

Comment: I've now removed the $function...

and now even the alert('Yeah'); is not even working? It didn't even show the message box Yeah for both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @MrCooL: There is an extra backslash character. `$(this\).ajaxSubmit(options);` should be `$(this).ajaxSubmit(options);`.

Comment: @MrCooL: Also, `imgEls.appendTo($('#slideShow'));` needs to be outside the `load` handler.

Comment: sorry for dragging this long. The slideshow still doesn't work in both Firefox and Chrome that I've tried. :(

Comment: @MrCooL: Now when I visit the page, Firebug says that all of the image requests are resulting in HTTP 500 Internal Server Error. It looks like you are using Django-nonrel. There must be an error that is occurring for the view servicing the images. Maybe try re-enabling debugging.

Comment: @MrCooL: The generated `<img>` tags seem malformed as the double quote terminating the `src` attribute value is missing. For example, `imgEls = imgEls.add($('<img src="/image?blob_key=AMIfv9...ROzrsQ width="350" height="350"" />'));` There should be a double quote after the blob key: `imgEls = imgEls.add($('<img src="/image?blob_key=AMIfv9...ROzrsQ" width="350" height="350"" />'));` (notice the extra double quote character before the width attribute).

Comment: Thanks for correcting that @Daniel Trebbien.

Do you have idea why sometimes it works and sometimes it don't. Either in Chrome or Firefox, when I click on Photo, it works. When I click other link and then clicked back again the Photo link, again, it didn't work. Even when it worked, it seems very slow as in I could see multiple images before the slideshow starts.

Is there other alternatives of Cycle plugin? Eventually, I would need to put this photo slideshow in a fancybox.

Comment: @MrCooL: The "multiple images" are due to the fact that the `#slideShow` `<div>` is visible while the images are loading. To fix this problem, add `style="display:none"` to the `<div>`, and just before calling the Cycle plugin, run `$("#slideShow").show();`, as in `$("#slideShow").show().cycle(...);` As far as alternatives, there are a number of jQuery slideshow plugins, but this one seems pretty good. If you want it in a fancybox, then just use the fancybox plugin and see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019533/slideshow-in-fancybox-image-gallery

Comment: hmnn...it seems that for now, the slideshow no longer working while just now it still worked sometimes...

My eventual solution, I would prefer fancybox picture gallery just like how Google Plus does with their Google+ So, I guess I'm switching to them since it still couldn't work properly with this Cycle plugin. But thumbs up for your great help ! ;)