# for fancybox, how can I start the slideshow automatically?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

there doesn't seem to be such an option, and I haven't figured out how to modify the source for this purpose. can anyone help me?

Comment: do u mean launch automatically fancybox slideshow or make it autoplay

Comment: read this post similar to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019533/slideshow-in-fancybox-image-gallery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to automatically display a gallery when the page load. I found the solution, it's just as simple as this:

```
$.fancybox.open($("[rel='your_rel']").get(), options);
```

This assumed you set the rel attribute of the items in the gallery to 'your_rel'.

Answer (score 5):

If using v2, then -

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    autoPlay : true, //  slideshow will start after opening the first gallery item
    playSpeed : 3000 // 3sec pause between changing next item
});
```

Comment: thanks, but i wanted to start the slideshow after page load, not after opening the first gallery item.

Comment: try $(".fancybox").fancybox({autoPlay: true, playSpeed : 3000}).trigger('click');

Comment: Note: `autoPlay` doesn't work in v2.1.4 (the one linked on fancyBox's homepage) with jquery 1.9.1 (test an earlier version of your choice - I had 1.6.2 and 1.8.2 handy, and they both work). Bug ticket submitted

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a version prior to V2.

Assuming that you already know how to make the gallery with the rel attribute and that your images now have a clickable next and previous button:

Simply add an auto click event on the id of next arrow #fancybox-right:

```
<script>
setInterval(function() {
    $('#fancybox-right').trigger('click');
}, 7000);
</script>
```

You can also use setTimeout, which will just click once and not continuously. 
Now if anyone knows how to make this setInterval stop on hover of div#fancybox-content, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with FancyBox 3:

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
        afterLoad: function() {

            if (!$('.fancybox-button--play').hasClass("fancybox-button--pause")) {
                $('.fancybox-button--play').trigger('click');
            }
        }
    });
```