# How do I get a image slider with Fancybox that automatically goes to the next

Tags: javascript, jquery

*I'm just started with webdesign and also working with Fancybox and I would like to know how to create a slider with 3 images that automatically goes to the next image, like they have on this site:

http://www.vigasnederland.nl/

Is this possible with Fancybox?

My html now:*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home - Van der Elst verhuizingen</title>
<style type="text/css">
#aboveheader {
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    background-color: #444444;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    color: #F5F5F5;
}



#navdiv {
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}
#imgdiv {
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #151515;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
#navdiv ul {
    margin-left: 20em;
}
#navdiv ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
#navdiv ul li a {
    display: block;
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid #1D1D1D;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #C3C3C3;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navdiv a:hover, #navdiv a:active, #navdiv a:focus, #navdiv a.thispage {
    color: #F9F9F9;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #232323;
}
.img  {
    position: relative;
    right: 2px;
    top: 15px;
}
.container {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.container .wrapper {
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/fancyBox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancyBox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div id="aboveheader"><a style="font size:40px; font-family: Cambria, 'Hoefler Text', 'Liberation Serif', Times, 'Times New Roman', serif; text-decoration: none; margin-left: 70px; color: #323232; background-color: #F7F7F7; padding: 10px; font-size: 40px;" href="#">Verhuisbedrijf Van der Elst</a><a style="text-decoration:none; font-size:25px; font-family:Cambria, 'Hoefler Text', 'Liberation Serif', Times, 'Times New Roman', serif; background-color: #120FE3; padding:10px; margin-left: 10em; color:#111111;" href="#">Bel ons op: 075-5971365</a> <a style="text-decoration: none; font size: 25px; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #323232; padding: 10px;" href="#">Contact</a></div>





    <div id="navdiv">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="thispage">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Onze diensten</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Offerte aanvragen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Over ons</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>

     </div>
    <div id="imgdiv"><a href="images/image1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="some-gallery-name"><img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="" name="image1" width="685" height="268" id="image1" style="position: relative; top: 100px; right: 20px;"/></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

When I view it in a browser, Fancybox is working fine but I want a slider that has autoplay just like the site I showed you above.
Maybe it's simple and probs I'm doing something wrong. And please tell me if you need to know anything else from me.

Comment: Seems to be same question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019533/slideshow-in-fancybox-image-gallery

Answer (score 0):

If my comment was right, the solution can be :

```
jQuery("a.fancybox").fancybox({
    "onComplete":function() {
        clearTimeout(jQuery.fancybox.slider);
        jQuery.fancybox.slider=setTimeout("jQuery.fancybox.next()",5000);
    }
});
```